# How to make Safari focus the webpage after submitting an URL in the address bar?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

Trying Safari again because Chrome uses too much CPU in comparison to Safari. However, when trying to use Vimari (the equilant of Vimium for Safari that lets you browse the web using the keyboard), after submitting an URL, the focus is still on the address bar, which causes my keyboard commands to be typed in the address bar instead.

**Q: How to make Safari focus on the page after submitting an URL?**

Comment: For anyone reading this: I switched to Opera, a few hours after asking this question. Really loving it so far: fast, smooth scrolling, low cpu, full screen support without address bar, vimium, address bar submit focuses the page.

Comment: I have been playing with Opera Developer, and it is also great. The only issue for me is the lack of integration with the auto-correct functionality.